# Hyperlink constant in MS-Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, hyperlink

I want to write a hyperlink constant into my MS-Access SQL code, like I can do with a string, date, numeric or Boolean constant. I guess this should be trivial, but I have looked in many other questions and I have not found the answer. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT "text#https://aa.bb.com" AS constant
SELECT #text#https://aa.bb.com# AS constant
SELECT "https://aa.bb.com" AS constant
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: `"text#https://aa.bb.com#"`. However, this will not be clickable from query. Bind textbox to field and set IsHyperlink property to Yes.

Comment: Many thanks. Setting IsHyperlink to yes works in a Form, but I cannot find that property in a Query (I think it does not exist). Any idea of how to make this work in a Query?

Comment: Can't. Why would you need it? Only a Hyperlink type field would be clickable in query.

Comment: In my Query I am doing a Union where one side contains table-fields with Hyperlink type and the other side contaisn hyperlink constants. I want the resulting Query to show clickable hyperlinks. I know (after your help) that I can solve it writing a Form over the Query, but I would like to avoid the Form (it would be the only Form in the database and I think it would confuse the user).

Comment: AFAIK, a constructed hyperlink string cannot be clickable in query. I think you cannot get what you want. Why would form confuse user? In Datasheet view it looks like a table/query. Set form to open by default when db opens.

Comment: What do you mean by "Union where one side contains table-fields with Hyperlink type and the other side contaisn hyperlink constants" - that sounds more like a JOIN.